# Convert PHP code to Python - Base64 with hmac-sha256

Tags: python

I have a code in PHP given below:

```
base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $message, $secret, true));
```

Now i want the same functionality in Python. Since i am a beginner with Python, please help me doing this.

Answer (score 0):

php code.

```
$s=base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', "Your message", 'secret', true));
echo $s;
```

Output: `xjyYPoGLbqdttWiTL7WPt6F5E9zl+3hjVaPftU/jvj8=`

Python code.

```
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac

message = "Your message"
hashValue = hmac.new(b"secret", message.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
base64Value = base64.b64encode(hashValue).decode()
print(base64Value)
```

Output: `xjyYPoGLbqdttWiTL7WPt6F5E9zl+3hjVaPftU/jvj8=`

Result: Both output are same.

Help: https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/